# Two different divs are showing up in the same style even though I specified different colours for each

Tags: html, css

I have these two divs (link blocks) that I want to be exactly the same just in different colours, but whenever I try to make one of the a different colour, it'll just change the div beside it as well.

Here is the code:

```
#nav1 a:link,a:visited { 
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none; 
  float: left;
 } 
#nav1 a:active,a:hover { 
  color: #000000;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
#nav2 a:link,a:visited { 
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none; 
  float: left;
} 
#nav2 a:active,a:hover { 
  color: #000000;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
```

I've made them each a different colour, but they both show up green/pink.

And the HTML:

```
<div id="nav1"><a href="">LINK1</a></div>
<div id="nav2"><a href="">LINK2</a></div>
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the `id` for each `a` state you're targeting, ex:

```
#nav1 a:link,a:visited {
```

should be

```
#nav1 a:link, #nav1 a:visited {
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/59by19ya/)

**NEW CSS**

```
#nav1 a:link, #nav1 a:visited { 
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: centerz;
  text-decoration: none; 
  float: left;
} 

#nav1 a:active, #nav1 a:hover { 
  color: #000000;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

#nav2 a:link, #nav2 a:visited { 
  color: #000000;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: green;
 width: 175px;
 padding-top: 17px;
 padding-bottom: 17px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none; 
 float: left;
} 

#nav2 a:active, #nav2 a:hover { 
  color: #000000;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
```